# Big-O of my function

Tags: python, big-o

I am trying to understand Big-O notation so I was making my own example for a O(n) using a while loop since I find while loops a bit confusing to understand in Big O notation. I defined a function called linear_example that takes in a list , the example is is python:

So my code is :

```
def linear_example (l):
    n =10
    while n>1:
        n -= 1
        for i in l:
            print(i)
```

My thought process is the code in the for loop runs in constant time O(1)
and the code in the while loop runs in O(n) time .
So there for it would be O(1)+O(n) which would evaluate to O(n).

Feedback?

Comment: I think it would be O(1)*O(n) instead of adding however I believe you are correct with your statement that it remains O(n). (Although I'm not great with big O notation so don't take my word for it :-)

Comment: For all practical purposes your function is O(n) where n is the list lenght. Big-O notation is a bit fuzzy and it is on purpose - you don't need to be that precise here (like taking into account every statement in the body of the function). That said this is borderline off-topic, you may want to ask this kind of question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Big O notation is used to use to describe the time complexity in relation to the input. Here code that iterates though your input is run a constant number of times. The for loop is O(N), the while loop only runs that a constant number of times therefore O(N)

Comment: @PauloScardine:  Noooo!  CodeReview is for exactly that: code reviews.  This is a question in complexity and foundations of computing.

Comment: Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues and ["Code Review or not?"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778)

Comment: @Prune sorry, English is not my native language and I thought he was asking for opinions - for me a question ended with "Feedback?" is the very definition of open-ended because in Portuguese it is the same as asking "Opinions?".

Answer (score 3):

Think of a simple for-loop:

```
for i in l:
    print(i)
```

This will be O(n) since you’re iterating through the list for however many items exist in l. (Where n == len(l))

Now we add a while loop which does the same thing ten times, so:

n + n + ... + n (x10)

And the complexity is O(10n).

Since this is still a polynomial with degree one, we can simplify this down to O(n), yes.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite.  First of all, `n` is not a fixed value, so **O(n)** is meaningless.  Let's assume a given value `M` for this, changing the first two lines:

```
def linear_example (l, M):
    n = M
```

The code in the `for` loop does run in **O(1)** time, provided that each element `i` of `l` is of finite bounded print time.  However, the loop iterates `len(l)` times, so the loop complexity is **O(len(l))**.

Now, that loop runs once *entirely* through for each value of `n` in the `while` loop, a total of `M` times.  Therefore, the complexity is the *product* of the loop complexities: **O(M * len(l))**.

Comment: Thank you all ! As suggested I will move my question to the code review section!